# Are there angel creation myths in Judaism?

Tags: malach-angel

Are there any angel creation myths in Judaism?

If there are, would you kindly post the myth or the link?

Thank you!

Comment: do you mean myths about angels being active in the act of creation, myths about angels being around and interacting with hashem during the time of creation, or something else entirely? As it is now I find it difficult to interpret your question

Comment: And the word myth is offensive since if Jews believe somthing to be TRUE it is not a myth for them it is truth

Comment: Do you mean about how angels are created and if they have existed from the beginning  or are created as needed for a particular use.

Comment: @hazoriz No it's not offensive. You just don't know what the word means. See the first and primary definition of the word here https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/myth : "A traditional story which embodies a belief regarding some fact or phenomenon of experience, and in which often the forces of nature and of the soul are personified; a sacred narrative regarding a god, a hero, the origin of the world or of a people, etc."

Comment: @DoubleAA, that may be primary, but that it's first doesn't imply as much. Wiktionary definitions are ordered sometimes by age of attestation, sometimes by frequency of use, sometimes by similarity of meaning (put similar ones together), sometimes by whim of editor.

Comment: @msh210 Either way it seems clearly to be what the OP meant.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://m.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/692875/jewish/What-Are-Angels.htm#footnoteRef10a692875)

> Another type of angels are those that are created through the deeds of man. In the words of our Sages: "He who fulfills one mitzvah, acquires for himself one angel-advocate; he who commits one transgression, acquires against himself one angel-accuser."([ovois 4.11](http://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.4.11) These are formed from the (intellectual and emotional) energy which one invests in the performance of a mitzvah, the study of Torah, or in prayer—or, conversely, energy applied in the execution of a sin.

Rashi [breraishis 1.5](http://m.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8165#showrashi=true)

> **one day**: According to the sequence of the language of the chapter, it should have been written, “the first day,” as it is written regarding the other days, “second, third, fourth.” Why did Scripture write“one”? Because the Holy One, blessed be He, was the only one in His world, for the angels were not created until the second day. [i.e., יוֹם אֶחָד is understood as ‘the day of the only One’]. So is it explained in Genesis Rabbah (3:8).

Breraishis Raba 3.10

10

> א"ר ינאי מתחלת ברייתו של עולם צפה הקב"ה מעשיהן של צדיקים ומעשיהם של רשעים. "וְהָאָרֶץ הָיְתָה תֹהוּ" אלו מעשיהם של רשעים "וַיֹּאמֶר אֱלֹהִים יְהִי אוֹר" אלו מעשיהן של צדיקים "וַיַּבְדֵּל אֱלֹהִים בֵּין הָאוֹר וּבֵין הַחֹשֶׁךְ" בין מעשיהן של צדיקים למעשיהן של רשעים. "וַיִּקְרָא אֱלֹהִים לָאוֹר יוֹם" אלו מעשיהן של צדיקים "וְלַחֹשֶׁךְ קָרָא לַיְלָה" אלו מעשיהן של רשעים. "וַיְהִי עֶרֶב" אלו מעשיהן של רשעים "וַיְהִי בֹקֶר" אלו מעשיהן של צדיקים. "יוֹם אֶחָד" שנתן להם הקדוש ברוך הוא יום אחד ואיזה זה יוה"כ. א"ר תנחום בר ירמיה שבו נבראו ארבעה דברים הרים שמים וארץ ואורה א"ר יודן שבו היה הקב"ה יחידי בעולמו שלא היה בעולמו אלא הוא אתיא כר' יוחנן ולא אתיא כרבי **חנינא רבי יוחנן אמר בשני נבראו המלאכים הה"ד (תהלים קד, ד ): "המקרה במים עליותיו השם עבים רכובו המהלך על כנפי רוח" וכתיב "עושה מלאכיו רוחות" רבי חנינא אמר בחמישי נבראו מלאכים שנאמר ועוף יעופף על הארץ וכתיב (ישעיה ו, ב ): "ובשתים יעופף" רבי לוליאני בר טבראי בשם ר' יצחק אמר בין על דעתיה דר"ח בין על דעתיה דר"י הכל מודים שלא נברא ביום הראשון** כלום שלא תאמר מיכאל היה מותח בדרומו של רקיע וגבריאל בצפונו והקדוש ברוך הוא ממדד באמצעיתו אלא (שם מד, כד) "אנכי ה' עושה כל נוטה שמים לבדי רוקע הארץ מאתי" מי אתי כתיב מי היה שותף עמי בברייתו של עולם:‏

Summary of bold
http://m.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/974948/jewish/When-were-the-angels-created.htm

Rabbi Noson says angels were created on Monday (second day of creation),
Rabbi Honina says on Thursday,
Rabbi Yitzhak says according to both of then they were not created on the first day

---

There is also the idea that when a Jew does a commandment he creates the body of the angle, and his intention creates the soul.